# How to implement Di in WinForms properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ninject, .net-framework-version

I am building a Winforms app.
I have few Projects
The main project is the winforms project
I have DB project (using EF core) and business project with my services
I am using Ninject for DI injection of the business services. I am initializing the StandartKernel in the main form with all my registered bindings.
So when i open a Form from the Main form i am passing the needed services from the kernel to the constructor of the form.
The problem is when i want to create a form from other form (not the main one)
Example:
From the Main Form i create ClientForm
But i want to add to the client's collection "Cars" a new object so I want to create a Car form directly from the ClientForm. And here is the problem: in the ClientForm i dont have CarService to pass to the new form, i have only ClientService.
What is the best solution to do the DI in such a project?
I am thinking to make all my services static but...
Any other solution?

Comment: Why not bootstrapping everything in program.cs? If it is not possible to bootstrap everything up-front, you probably should bootstrap factories, which are capable to create your components when needed.

Comment: Agree with above comment. If you are used to project types such as ASP.NET (core) and things like this, the library does this bootstrapping for you. You just have to set it up manually in the Program class (or any other class that is called pre-forms load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was working with something like that these days. I was using the `Unity Container` to make my DI. The code is not entirely complete and not optimized at all.

If you've seen or used ASP.NET APIs, I tried to play the same operation in a windows forms application.

I used a extension method like below to add all my forms to the Unity Container.

```
    public static void AddForms(this IUnityContainer container, Assembly assembly = null)
    {
        if (assembly == null) assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

        foreach (var form in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Form).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
        {
            var initForm = form.GetCustomAttribute<InitialFormAttribute>();
            if (initForm != null)
            {
                container.RegisterType(typeof(Form), form, "InitialForm", new TransientLifetimeManager());
            }
            else
            {                    
                container.RegisterType(form, new TransientLifetimeManager());
            }

        }
    }
```

And use some coding to implements the startup just like in ASP.NET. At startup I added the EF Core DbContext to the container, just as I added everything I needed to be able to simply make the Unity Container create the instances of the forms for me, and I always have access to my services within the forms.

If you want to see the full code, comment below.